# NHibernate not updating all properties of entities

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm experiencing an odd problem with FluentNHibernate: when I save my entity, one of the (reference) properties is not updated. Other properties, both fields and references, are updated, and the failing property is correctly mapped (retrieving entities works like a charm).

A (slightly simplified) description of what I'm doing:

1. Into my MVC action method, an `InputModel` is bound and set. It has a property for the `TypeID`, where I wish to set the `Type` of my entity (let's call the entity type `Thing`).
2. A new `Thing` object is created, and the simple properties of the `InputModel` is copied over. For a couple of complex properties, among them the `Type` property which isn't working and another property which is, the following is done:
   2.1. The correct `ThingType` is fetched from the repository, based on the provided type id.
   2.2. The type is set (using `thing.Type = theType`) on the new `Thing` object.
3. The `Thing` that I want to update is fetched from the repository, based on the id on the input model (not the same id as the `TypeID`).
4. All properties, complex and other, are copied over from the new thing (created by me) to the original one (fetched from db).
5. The original `Thing` is saved, using `session.Save();`.

As stated above, it's only one property that isn't working - other properties, following (as far as I can tell) the exact same pattern, work. I've also debugged and verified that the original `Thing` has the correct, updated `Type` when it is passed to `session.Save()`.

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this...

**Update**: The classes are plain POCOs:

```
public class Thing 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeSimpleProp { get; set; }
    public ThingType Type { get; set; }
    public OtherEntity OtherReference { get; set; }
}
public class ThingType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My exact mappings (except for the names of types and properties) are these:

```
// In ThingMap : ClassMap<Thing> constructor:
Id(t => t.ID).Column("ThingID");
Map(t => t.SomeSimpleProp);
References(t => t.Type).Column("ThingTypeID");
References(t => t.OtherReference).Column("OtherReferenceID");

// In ThingTypeMap : ClassMap<ThingType> constructor:
Id(t => t.ID).Column("ThingTypeID");
Map(t => t.Name);
```

As I said, `OtherReference` is updated correctly while `Type` is not. They are mapped identically, so I don't see how this could be a mapping error.

Comment: If the entity comes from the database, you don't need to call session.Save. Provide some (relevant) real code and / or mappings (please reduced to the parts that matter).

Comment: how did you set mapping?

Comment: @Stefan: After further investigating this, I found that it was a transaction problem stemming from me trying to call session.Save(). If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted =)

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `<many-to-one .... cascade="save-update"/>` in order to update references.

Comment: To clarify: It's not the actual `Type` that has been updated - just which type the `Thing` references. Does this still apply? Because it's working on the other properties without this...

Comment: @Tomas Lycken may be providing the map and classes int the question could help.